# Cancel stripe subscription via information in metadata

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to cancel a subscription via parsing the stripe customer list and searching in each of them if the meta data matches.

Currently this is not working.

```
customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)
for c in customers.auto_paging_iter():
    if bool(c.metadata):
        try:
            if user.username == c.metadata.username:
                for s in c.subscriptions.data:
                    subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(s['id'])
                    subscription.delete(at_period_end=True)
                commit()
                return jsonify(status=True)
        except:
            continue
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The code looks okay. Could you clarify what is not working exactly? Do you get an error, or does nothing happen and you're just observing that subscriptions that you expect to be canceled are untouched?

Comment: so I just figured it out, apparently `subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(s['id'])` does not work, it has to be `subscription = c.subscriptions.retrieve(s['id'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I just figured it out, apparently

```
subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(s['id'])
```

does not work

it has to be

```
subscription = c.subscriptions.retrieve(s['id'])
```

Comment: Ah, you might be using an older version of the Python bindings that doesn't have support for retrieving subscriptions directly. It was added in version [1.33.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/61707d90b855a6299f08f581755da108a3fbd30a/CHANGELOG#L38-L44).

Comment: if I updated is it reverse compatible? Since I already pushed the update and haven't updated pip

Comment: The updated version should be fully backwards-compatible -- Stripe updates the major version number when breaking changes are introduced.